# How to calculate the width of the separating margin in support vector machine (SVM)

Tags: optimization, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

There are 4 points, $\mathrm x_1 = (1,1,0,1), \;\mathrm x_2= (1,1,0,-1) , \; \mathrm x_3 = (-1,1,0,1) , \; \mathrm x_4 = (1,-2,0,1)$ in a 4-Dimensional Euclidean space.

Let the labels of $x_1$ and $x_2$ be $+1$ and of $x_3$ and $x_4$ be $-1.$

Suppose there is a separating hyperplane between the two labels given by $\mathrm w^\top \mathrm x = 0,$ where $\mathrm w = (4,3,0,0).$

Calculate margin of separating hyperplane. Please explain the procedure as well.

Comment: Please note that although the question is perfectly valid, someone downvoted it probably because you didn't show what solutions you had explored. Notice also that there is plenty of information on the topic elsewhere within the scope of SE communities, such as in [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23391/67822).

Comment: Sorry, its actually my first question. Also, I have explored plenty of sources but could not come up with a concrete solution to the problem. Would be great if someone could help me out!

Comment: @amWhy Please note that the correct spelling is "Euclidean."  After missing out on this point on my first edit of the question yesterday, I submitted a re-edit for completeness sake, indicating that lingering mistake. I see you edited it yourself overriding my request, but your typed it incorrectly as " Euclidian." Wouldn't make a fuss of it if Euclid wasn't who he is in maths :-)

Comment: It is now corrected; thanks for keeping on top of this, @AntoniParellada